# Replacing croatian diacritic characters

Tags: javascript, string, replace

I have script where people put their names and script generates different name based on the first character of their real name.

```
    var firstNm = document.getElementById("Ime").value.toUpperCase();
```

Those new names I have in array from 65-90(A-Z).
Procedure to get first letter is like this:

```
var firstNum = firstNm.charCodeAt(0) - 65;
    if (firstNum < 0 || firstNum > 25) {
        validName = false;
```

but before that, I would like to change all characters like "ŠIME" to "SIME" when user types ŠIME,
I tried with this, but it seems not to work

```
$(function() { 
  $('Ime').keyup(function() {
    $(this).val($(this).val().replace(/Š/g, "S"));
  });
});
```

Comment: Given the poor Unicode support in Javascript, I'm not sure you'll be able to do that (easily).

Comment: Seems to work fine http://jsbin.com/uhixoz/1/edit. Tested in Chrome and Firefox

Comment: What exactly does not work? Seems fine to me. Please provide a demo with the buggy code.

Comment: @zneak: See http://lehelk.com/2011/05/06/script-to-remove-diacritics/ for example (not a performant replacer, though)

Comment: @Bergi, this solution doesn't account for standalone diacritics. Every diacritic also exists as a standalone character that you can add as a suffix to any character.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry guys, thanks for your help, I solved myself the problem, by adding function like this

```
function zamjenaZnakovaI(){
var tekst = document.getElementById("Ime").value;
tekst.indexOf( 'Č' ) == 0? tekst = tekst.replace( 'Č', 'C' ) : 
tekst.indexOf( 'č' ) == 0? tekst = tekst.replace( 'č', 'c' ) : 
tekst.indexOf( 'Ć' ) == 0? tekst = tekst.replace( 'Ć', 'C' ) : 
tekst.indexOf( 'ć' ) == 0? tekst = tekst.replace( 'ć', 'c' ) : 
tekst.indexOf( 'Š' ) == 0? tekst = tekst.replace( 'Š', 'S' ) : 
tekst.indexOf( 'š' ) == 0? tekst = tekst.replace( 'š', 's' ) : 
tekst.indexOf( 'Ž' ) == 0? tekst = tekst.replace( 'Ž', 'Z' ) :
tekst.indexOf( 'ž' ) == 0? tekst = tekst.replace( 'ž', 'z' ) :
tekst.indexOf( 'Đ' ) == 0? tekst = tekst.replace( 'Đ', 'D' ) :
tekst.indexOf( 'đ' ) == 0? tekst = tekst.replace( 'đ', 'd' ) :
tekst;
document.getElementById("Ime").value = tekst;
}
```

Because I only needed replaced first letter in string, not fifth or fourth

and I called function on keyup

```
<input type="text" id="Ime" size="30"  onkeyup="zamjenaZnakovaI()"/>
```

Maybe there is better solution, but this one works.
So if anyone else would need something similar, here is the one way in wich could be done.

Cheers, D.

Answer (score 0):

You can find my JavaScript port of the Apache Lucene ASCII Folding Filter at https://github.com/mplatt/fold-to-ascii-js

It converts Unicode characters which are not in the first 127 ASCII characters into their ASCII equivalents.

It handles the characters you posted (and many more).